# Retain directory Structure after compression in hdfs

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, gzip, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to compress data in hdfs using the following hadoop streaming job

> hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0-cdh5.5.0.jar             -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=0             -Dmapred.output.compress=true             -Dmapred.compress.map.output=true             -Dmapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec -Dmapreduce.input.fileinputformat.input.dir.recursive=true -input /sample/data -output /output -mapper /bin/cat

I have the following directory structure

```
/sample
   /data
      /monday mon.txt
      /tuesday tue.txt
      /wednesday wed.txt
```

when I give the input as /sample/data/ all the files are compressed to a single file and when I uncompress it the directory structure is not retained.

Inorder to retain the directory structure I have to run the job for each of the folder which is /sample/data/monday, /sample/data/tuesday and so on.

Is there a easy way for me to compress the data in a single job using "sample/data" as input such a way that the directory structure is retained when i uncompress it.(I can move to any other compression techniques if they support to retain the structure).

Thanks